# using colorScheme vs accent color

Tags: flutter

i know colorscheme is now instead of accent color
and I want to use color scheme instyling Textbutton for example
but when i use it in styling there is a problem in types different so I make a cast like that

```
itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Card(
color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme as Color
```

,
or

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme as Color)
```

is that right or wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`Theme.of(context).colorScheme` provides list of color, you can't use like it where you need to pass single color.

To use `primary` color from `colorScheme` you n need to specify

```
 primary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
```

More about [ColorScheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)